# How do I draw a filled rectangle using OpenCV's drawing functions?

Tags: python, opencv, video, homography

I have written a Python script that basically parses a video frame by frame and uses feature matching + Homography to detect similarities to a given image and draws a bounding box around the area where the image appears in the video. I'm very new to OpenCV, hence I cannot really understand which function to use to draw a filled rectangle instead of a bounding box (I'm using polylines).

I'm guessing I have to use 'fillpoly' or 'fillConvexPoly' but I'm confused as to which parameters to use and how to implement it. Here's my code so far.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    img = cv2.imread("template.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'xvid')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 25.0, (1280,718))

    # Features
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kp_image, desc_image = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)

    # Feature matching
    index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
    search_params = dict()
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

    while True :
        _, frame = cap.read()
        grayframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        kp_grayframe, desc_grayframe = sift.detectAndCompute(grayframe, None)
        matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_image, desc_grayframe, k=2)

        good_points = []
        for m, n in matches:
            if m.distance < 0.6 * n.distance:
                good_points.append(m)

        if (len(good_points)>10):
            query_pts = np.float32([kp_image[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good_points]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
            train_pts = np.float32([kp_grayframe[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good_points]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
            matrix, mask = cv2.findHomography(query_pts, train_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
            matches_mask = mask.ravel().tolist()

            # Perspective transform
            h, w = img.shape
            pts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h], [w, h], [w, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
            dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, matrix)

            homography = cv2.polylines(frame, [np.int32(dst)], True, (0,255, 0), 3) #this is the line i want to change
            out.write(homography)
            cv2.imshow("Homography", homography)

        else:
            cv2.imshow("Homography", grayframe)


        cv2.imshow("grayFrame", grayframe)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, Anriban Nath! If you edit your question adding **Python** and **OpenCV** versions you're using it would let people help you easly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mention yourself, you can use `cv2.fillPoly()`.

You may want to take a look to the `cv2.fillPoly()` documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly).

or to these related SO questions:

- [What does the python interface to opencv2.fillPoly want as input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270250/what-does-the-python-interface-to-opencv2-fillpoly-want-as-input)
- [Opencv how to fill a polyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121978/opencv-how-to-fill-a-polyline)

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = np.zeros(shape=(512, 512, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
points = np.array([[225, 150], [103, 320], [350, 250], [222, 245]],
                  dtype=np.int32)

cv2.fillPoly(image, [points], (0, 255, 0))
cv2.imshow('polygon', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]